# Log cat going crazy, logging phone too and not just app?

Tags: java, android, logcat

When I connect my phone log cat goes crazy, it prints tons and tons of messages and never stops.  I can't write any useful debug logging because it gets lost immediately by the tons of other messages getting printed out.

It wasn't always doing this, it just started up recently.  Tried restarting eclipse and unplugging/pluggin back in the phone.

Why is log cat doing this?  It's like it's tied into the phone and everything going on but I don't want that, I just want my app...

Comment: idk why its like that mines like that too, but i use filter and make a tag in my logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal.  Logcat collects logs from every app on your device.  You will want to create filters based on tags or your package name to make it useful.